# Adding attribute to element dynamically does not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote directive to get all elements with `ng-model` directive and add to them `ng-change` attribure with some value.Attributes added to the DOM. But value (function) in them does not call.

**My directive**

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('updateFields', updateFields);
updateFields.$inject = ['$timeout', '$compile'];
function updateFields($timeout, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, arrt) {
            $timeout(() => {
                var elements = angular.element("[ng-model]");
                console.log(elements);
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    var el = elements[i];
                    var fullProperty = elements[i].getAttribute("ng-model");
                    var property = fullProperty.replace("vm.Account.", '');
                    var ngChangeAttr = elements[i].attributes["ng-change"];

                    if (ngChangeAttr) {
                        el.setAttribute('ng-change', ngChangeAttr.value + ";" + "vm.actions.updateField( " + "'" + property + "'," + fullProperty + ")");
                    } else {
                        el.setAttribute('ng-change', "vm.actions.updateField( " + "'" + property + "'," + fullProperty + ")");
                    }
                   $compile(el)(scope);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does fullProperty have characters in it that are resulting in a broken attribute?

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins Seems it does not

Comment: You are compiling with current scope, and on current scope you probably don't have a vm.actions.updateField function.
I don't know why you need to do it like that, there is probably better way to do it - more elegant

Comment: @Darkves Thank you. But i need to use this directive on the several places. Do you have any idea how can i do it better?